# How to hide a clicked link in Javascript and save in session

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I have a simple game application using Java, JSP's and CSS. When a question is clicked on the game board, it takes the user to another JSP (the question) and when the user submits their answer, they are taken back to the game board.

**My HTML:**

```
<td id="link"><a href="QuestionServy?question=0" onclick="myFunction()">100</a></td>
```

**My Javascript:**

```
function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = ""; 
}
```

The problem is that when a user chooses a question and submits, they are redirected back to the game board page, and the state isn't saved.

I have researched and found that you can use sessionStorage, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT:**

What the program currently looks like:
[game board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dse1X.jpg)

What it should look like after first link has been clicked:
[game board after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcUHh.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You <strike>can</strike> need to use [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

#### Question page

You can use the `getItem` and `setItem` functions easily like so:

```
function myFunction () {
    window.localStorage.setItem('answer1', 'bla bla bla');
    ...

    document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = "";
}
```

#### Answer page

You can get this value anywhere in the app (even between different sessions) like so:

```
var answer1 = window.localStorage.getItem('answer1');
```

## Update

`sessionStorage` is only saved for a single session, and (as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage))

> Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated

Since you are opening the *Question page* in a new tab, and not within the same page ([SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) style), your `sessionStorage` will expire.

#### Solution

Just replace `window.sessionStorage` with `window.localStorage`

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm still not getting it for some reason - When I open link in a new tab in browser, you can see that the link disappears (which is what I want) however, when you refresh the page (or the user gets redirected back to page) the link appears again. I've been at this for 3 days, feeling very frustrated!

Comment: Can you post the code for (perhaps) storing and retrieving the variable used for appearing and disappearing of the link? Also, make sure you are reading the variable initially from `window.localStorage.getItem()`, and not always initializing it to a default value

Comment: I've put all files into PasteBin (if that's ok!):

Comment: Question page: http://pastebin.com/RmwmGEAe

Game Board: http://pastebin.com/k2m68c1f

JS: http://pastebin.com/JTZ0Zjr6

Comment: Thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save session storage you can use below code

```
window.localStorage.setItem("variable name","value to be store");
```

Implimented in your code as below

```
  function myFunction() {
        window.localStorage.setItem("qustn-no","0");
        document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = ""; 
    }
```

You can retrieve this value on next page or any other page by writing below code

```
var abc=window.localStorage.getItem("qustn-no");
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! Still not working - see my comment to Anubhav Dhawan above